# Setting VueJS inner component attrs based on prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

Perhaps messing around with something obvious in VueJS syntax, but I can not make this `Button.vue` SFC to work:

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
    ...
    href: String,
    ...
});
</script>

...

<template>

<Link :href="href"
      :as="href == null ? 'button' : null"
      :type="href == null ? 'button' : null">
    <slot />
</Link>

</template>
```

I simply want that if there is `href`, `Link` is treated like an anchor, with href.
**But** if no `href` prop coming, it is treated as a regular button, adding `as="button"` and `type="button"` to the Link component attrs.

But the browser console output that I get when instantiating a `Button`, e.g., with `href="register"` is this:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <Link href="http://myproject.test/register" as=null type=null  ...>
```

`href` value is fine in this case, as `href` prop is provided, but look at the `as=null type=null` part...
Looks like "null" is not treated as `null`.

Using Vue3 by the way :)

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what's wrong with current code?

Comment: Where is the Link component defined?

Comment: My bad. Edited with the browser console output, of course.

Comment: As couteau mentioned where's the Link component defined?

Comment: Link component comes from InertiaJS. I simply import it at the beginning with `import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";`, so I think that is not the case. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If null is the issue then You can try this

```
<Link :href="href"
      :as="href == null ? 'button' : a"
      :type="href == null ? 'button' : a">
    <slot />
</Link>
```

In inertia Link component **as** props refer to HTML tag name

Comment: It has no sense, as I am now getting an error like this: `[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <Link href="http://myproject.test/register" as="a" type="a" />`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. Looking at Vue3 docs, I saw that optional props, when not present, evaluate as `undefined`, not as `null` like in Vue2.

Then, simply substituting every `null` appearance to `undefined` in my code did the trick.